# Sort Associate array by datetime key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, associative-array

I have an array with different index positions like this.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 27/01/2017 12:18
        [location] => Raunheim (DE)
        [date] => 27/01/2017
        [time] => 12:18
        [status] => Erfolgreich zugestellt.
        [status_1] => (Retoure an Versender)
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 11/01/2017 16:10
        [location] => Vlotho (DE)
        [date] => 11/01/2017
        [time] => 16:10
        [status] => Ihr Paket konnte nicht wie geplant zugestellt werden und ist wieder im Paketzustellzentrum.
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [datetime] => 25/01/2017 11:24
        [status] => Erfolgreich zugestellt.
        [status_id] => 
        [date] => 25/01/2017
        [location] => Altentreptow (DE)
        [time] => 11:24
    )
)
```

I want to sort this array using datetime key. I have tried solutions

```
usort($second_tracking_array, 'date_compare');
function date_compare($a, $b) {

    $date1 = $a['datetime'];
    $date2 = $b['datetime'];

    $t1 = strtotime($date1);
    $t2 = strtotime($date2);

    echo $t1 . " : " . $t2 . "</br>";
    return $t2 - $t1;
}
```

But the array is not sorting. On debugging i have found that the functions works and sort the array only if all the index positions are right. But in my case some of my array index positions are different.

Comment: You can't have the same key 2 times like in your example (2x key 2). You can fix your array key with `$array = array_values($array);`

Comment: But each index of array contains only one datetime key. The problem i am facing that in function date_compare i often get $t2 empty. I get $t1 and $t2 with timestamp only if both comparing array have same structured array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your strategy to parse the date strings. Reason is that the format your datetime strings *apparently* have is not any standard conform variant.

```
<?php

define('CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT', 'd/m/Y G:i');

$second_tracking_array = [
    [
        'datetime' => '27/01/2017 12:18',
        'location' => 'Raunheim (DE)',
        'date' => '27/01/2017',
        'time' => '12:18',
        'status' => 'Erfolgreich zugestellt.',
        'status_1' => '(Retoure an Versender)'
    ],
    [
        'datetime' => '11/01/2017 16:10',
        'location' => 'Vlotho (DE)',
        'date' => '11/01/2017',
        'time' => '16:10',
        'status' => 'Ihr Paket konnte nicht wie geplant zugestellt werden und ist wieder im Paketzustellzentrum.'
    ],
    [
        'datetime' => '25/01/2017 11:24',
        'status' => 'Erfolgreich zugestellt.',
        'status_id' => '',
        'date' => '25/01/2017',
        'location' => 'Altentreptow (DE)',
        'time' => '11:24'
    ]
];

usort(
    $second_tracking_array,
    function($a, $b) {
        $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat(CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT, $a['datetime']);
        $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat(CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT, $b['datetime']);
        return $date1 > $date2;
    }
);

print_r($second_tracking_array);
```

The obvious output of above is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 11/01/2017 16:10
            [location] => Vlotho (DE)
            [date] => 11/01/2017
            [time] => 16:10
            [status] => Ihr Paket konnte nicht wie geplant zugestellt werden und ist wieder im Paketzustellzentrum.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 25/01/2017 11:24
            [status] => Erfolgreich zugestellt.
            [status_id] =>
            [date] => 25/01/2017
            [location] => Altentreptow (DE)
            [time] => 11:24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 27/01/2017 12:18
            [location] => Raunheim (DE)
            [date] => 27/01/2017
            [time] => 12:18
            [status] => Erfolgreich zugestellt.
            [status_1] => (Retoure an Versender)
        )

)
```

Comment: @HabibQadoos Sure, you are welcome. I just further simplified the code by removing the call to `getTimestamp()` which is not actually required.